# Return a Observable from a Subscription with RxJS

Tags: javascript, angular, rxjs

I currently have a service that do a HTTP request to an API to fetch data. There are some logic that I want to do to the observable from within the service, but I still want to also subscribe to the Observable in my Component so that I can return any errors to the Component and to the user.

Currently I do:

```
// service.ts
getData(): Observable<any> {
    return this.http.get(url).pipe(catchError(this.handleError)
}

// component.ts
ngOnInit() {
    this.service.getData().subscribe(res => {
        // Do my logic that belong to the service.ts
        // ...

        // Do my logic that belongs in the component.ts
        // ...
    }, err => this.errors = err)
}
```

What I would like to do is to refactor this so that I handle the logic related to the subscription and the service.ts within the getData() method, and then return an Observable with the HTTP response and any errors to the Component so that I can continue doing things there.

What's the pattern to do this?

Comment: missing a ) at the end of 'pipe(catchError(this.handleError)'

Answer (score 46, accepted):

I feel like multiple of the patterns and solutions posted is "ugly" or does not follow the `Observable` pattern (Like doing callbacks).

The cleanest, most "RxJS"-like solution I came up with was to wrap the service method's return value in a second Observable.

So the following:

```
// service.ts
getData(): Observable<any> {
    return new Observable(subscriber => {
        this.http.get(url)
          .pipe(catchError(this.handleError)
          .subscribe(res => {
              // Do my service.ts logic.
              // ...
              subscriber.next(res)
              subscriber.complete()
          }, err => subscriber.error(err))
    })
}

// component.ts
ngOnInit() {
    this.service.getData().subscribe(res => {
        // Do my component logic.
        // ...
    }, err => this.errors = err)
}
```

Comment: I don't understand why this post doesn't have any points. Thanks a lot!

Comment: Why is `(observer: Observer)` necessary and what do `observer.next(res)` and `observer.complete()` do?

Comment: You should lookup what the ‘Observer’ class is. Note that it’s different from ‘Observable’.

Comment: I wouldn't say that this is the most "RxJs-like" solution. It's better practice and leads to cleaner code if you chain multiple operators in your `pipe` and do your service logic within those operators.

Comment: This is an elegant solution that would probably be very useful in other situations as well. I simply think it is unnecessary in your situation. Did you try the `tap()` function? https://rxjs-dev.firebaseapp.com/api/operators/tap

Comment: @DevMoviit Exactly. This answer solves the question from the title `How to return an Observable from a Subscription with RxJS` but doing so isn't the best way to separate service logic from component logic when dealing with Observables. Instead of subscribing in the service one should leverage the power of [operators](http://reactivex.io/documentation/operators.html). There is a [decision tree](https://rxjs-dev.firebaseapp.com/operator-decision-tree) to help pick the right one. In this case `tap` is probably what the OP needs.

Comment: bro, I have been SCOWERING the internet for this, THANK YOU!

Comment: This is fantastic - I didn't understand the subscriber.next function until you used it here - absolutely fantastic usage of Observables and a great way to wrap functions without lazy usage of `of()`.

Answer (score 1):

Use `map`:

```
// service.ts:

import { catchError, map } from 'rxjs/operators';

getData(): Observable<any> {
    return this.http.get(url).pipe(
        map(res => {
            /* Your processing here */
            return res;
        }),
        catchError(this.handleError)
    )
}
```

Comment: Seems like when using `map()` the object passed in is still the Observable, so I can't access any of the response yet. E.g. `res.data` would not work.

Comment: res passed to map is not an observable, normally

Answer (score 0):

Try this way

```
service.ts

getData(): Observable<any> {
  return this.http.get(url).map(res=> <any>(res['_body']));
}

component.ts

this.service.getData().subscribe(response=>{
            var res1 = JSON.stringify(response);
            var res2 = JSON.parse(res1);
            var res3 = JSON.parse(res2);
});  //parse response based on your response type
```

Answer (score 0):

***Option 1***

If you subscribe `Observable` in component then only component will have that subscription and it must be passed back to `service`.

***Option 2***

Use this pattern.

*service.ts*

```
    getData(doer: Function) {
        let subscriptions = Observable.of({ data: 'response', isError: false })// request
            .catch(error => Observable.of({ data: error, isError: true })) //handle error
            .do(data => doer(data))
            .subscribe();
        this.handleSubscription(subscriptions); //subscription handling in service
    }
```

*component.ts*

```
    ngOnInit() {
        this.getData(response => {
            if (response.isError) {
                ///
            } else {
                let data = response.data;
                // Process
            }
        })
    }
```

Comment: Is a callback really the right way to do it? That sounds very counter-intuitive considering Observables are suppose to get rid of callback pattern.

Comment: Yes then go for Option 1. Make a normal `getData()` method which return final data after handling error. From `component` pass the subscription back to `service`  so it can handle the subscription.

Answer (score -1):

Be careful: All the answers are for <= Angular 4. In Angular 5, you don't need a `map()` anymore, so just leave that out. just return `this.http.get()` as it returns an Observable, where you can subscribe on.

Furthermore, be aware you have to import `HttpClient` instead of `Http`.

Comment: You seem to miss the point of the question. The question is how to do logic on the observable both in the service and in the component, the question is not how to return an Observable.

Answer (score -1):

You can directly use "map" and "catch" function on Observable returned by http.get method.

```
import { catchError, map } from 'rxjs/operators';

getData(): Observable<any> {
    return this.http.get(url)
        .map(res => {
            /* Your processing here */
            return res;
        })
        .catch(this.handleError);
}
```

Answer (score -2):

You can remove `this`, and use `map`. In subscribe error, you can get error event.

If you use HttpClient, just use get!