# Angular httpClient get headers if an error occurred

Tags: angular, angular-httpclient

I tried the following code, but the headers attribute is not defined. Is there another way to access the http header if the http response status is not 2xx?

```
this._httpClient.get(url)

      .subscribe(
        (res: any) => {
          //sth
        },
        error => {
          this._logger.error(..., error.headers.get('Some-important-header'));

        }
      );
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The response body doesn't return all the data you may need. Sometimes servers return special headers or status codes to indicate certain conditions that are important to the application workflow.

Tell HttpClient that you want the full response with the observe option:

```
this.httpClient.get(url, { observe: "response" }).subscribe(
            (res: any) => {
              //sth
            },
            error => {
              this._logger.error(..., error.headers.get('Some-important-header'));

            }
          );
```

Hope this will help you!

Comment: This returns a subscrpition, not the observable.

Comment: You can return an observable from the subscription. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49630371/return-a-observable-from-a-subscription-with-rxjs

Comment: No you can't. And if you had read the question you have provided, you would have seen that it isn't true : the guy creates an observable and sends a value to that stream **through the subscription**. The subscription doesn't return anything, because it simply can't.

Comment: Besides the return it works for me, when I add the `{ observe: "response" }`

Answer (score 0):

Try something like this

```
this._httpClient.get(url).pipe(tap(event  => {
   if(event instanceof HttpResponse){
      console.log(event.headers);
   }
}), catchError(this.handleError));
```

**Handle Error**

```
private handleError(error: HttpErrorResponse) {
    if (error instanceof HttpErrorResponse) {
      console.log(error.headers);
    } 
  };
```

Just read it when you get the response - Hope this helps - happy coding :)